# I got Dire AIDS. What are its negative effects?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I got Dire AIDS from battling 'Dire' wildlife in Canada.

[image: Dire AIDS - Kills you slowly, but faster than regular AIDS. Not curable by normal means.]

Suppose I didn't have it [cured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geuly.png), are there any negative gameplay effects if I have it?

Comment: Well, there's an achievement for beating the game without curing it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get a debuff at every fight. If i recall correctly: minor health drain at every turn.

Answer (score 13):

Dire AIDS inflicts a combat debuff on your player that causes minor health damage each turn.

Unlike other debuffs, Dire AIDS has no duration, persists in between combats, and is not curable through consumable items. The only way to get rid of it is to visit the hospital in Canada.

Dire AIDS does have some benefit. If you complete the final battle while inflicted, you get rewarded with an achievement.